# Samsung 850 EVO SSD can't install Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd

I have problem with SSD (Samsung 850 EVO 120GB) and Windows 10. It's empty SSD bought today and I can't install Windows 10 on it, because when I click next in partition window it gives me error: "we couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one".

I'm installing Windows 10 from USB 3.0. I tried to install Windows 8 from CD and I am able to install it fine. Tried to upgrade from 8 to 10, but after upgrade completes I have a black screen and nothing happens. Could it be related to SSD driver or something? I'm super confused as I have never had such problem.. :(

Comment: I doubt it's the hard drive. Have you tried making a LiveUSB or disk of the Windows 10 install with [Windows DVD/USB tool](https://wudt.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: @Dooley_labs I have not tried LiveUSB. I will try that. I tried making bootable usb with windows media creation tool and rufus, both gave error when installing. Upgrade to windows 10 did install, but on first boot got black screen.

Comment: a LiveUSB is a bootable usb, btw :3

Comment: Yeah I thought so. I will make one in a bit and tell the results.

Comment: Maybe there are any other ideas? I am creating liveusb atm from windows 8 running on that ssd.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I tried last time to install clean windows 10 and it worked perfectly! :) Thanks @Dooley_labs for helping! :)

Comment: can you redownload the win10 iso? Sounds like a corrupt iso imho

Comment: Probably an MBR vs. GPT issue.  I forget the exact details, but a "EUFI" installer will fail to recognize MBR disks, and a "legacy" installer will refuse to recognize GPT or something along those line.  This is also an issue with *rescue disks* that caused me immense difficulties at one point.  (Note that MBR and GPT are partitioning strategies for disks, not something intrinsic to the disks themselves)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same issue. In the end, I ended up having to disable my raid controller because it was causing my raid array to show up as the first drive in the list of drives in Windows setup on the "Where do you want to install Windows?" page. Once I did this, my new SSD showed up as the first drive, and I was able to install successfully on the new SSD. I was unable to find any other way to force the BIOS to put the SSD drive first. Luckily, this had no effect on the raid array; after installation I enabled the raid controller again and all was well.